Delta Sigma ADC polarity confusion
We have a working circuit that measures motor phase currents and passes it along to an MCU's internal ADC.
This is the circuit:

Notice that the output will be 'inverted' , so in software we invert it back to get back the correct value.
We want to replace the above circuit with a Sigma-Delta Modulator such as the AMC1303M0510.

Reading through the data sheet , they say that if the differential input is 50mv , that would mean a duty cycle pulses of 89.06 %., The MCU's SDFM module reads these pulses and gives out a value based on the resolution set in software.(As shown in the figure above)


The 'Differential input' here is referred as (AINN - AINP) OR (AINP -
AINN)?
If voltage at AINN > AINP, does this mean the Duty cycle is between
(50 to 89.06)

OR

If voltage at AINP > AINN, does this mean the Duty cycle is between
(50 to 89.06)

Please help clear this confusion.
Thankyou!

Note that the AMC1303 is a delta-sigma modulator, not a complete ΔΣ ADC.

Hi Hearth, yes i am aware it is a modulator , i have corrected in my post.


well i also work on a 400V motor driver but I use AMC1300 IC .you want see some details in data sheet .

here the long story short .
Vin=Ainp-Ainn
INP=0V (Exactly) OP=will give a pulse of 50% duty cycle respect to your frequency.
INP=+50mv(Full scale) OP=1 pulse with 89.06% duty cycle (MCU read as "1" )
INP=-50mv(Full Scale) OP=1 pulse with 10.94% duty cycle (MCU read as "0" )
Clipping mode :
Only Zeros(pulse width 10.96%) are transmitted if input is ≤ –64 mV.
Only Ones (Pulse width 89.06%)are transmitted if input is ≥ +64 mV.
so the consolidated answer is
consider 0V as a center point
If AINP>AINN: Duty cycle is 50% to 89.06% (positive input).
If AINN>AINP: Duty cycle is 50% to 10.94% (negative input).
your assumption is correct.
This is the simulation I've done: Actually it has to be done more precisely and the ADC output is read in MCU only.



Thx for your  answer Vikraman, By any chance, Have you confirmed this on an oscilloscope?

Actually not . I done a simulation for this. I will share the Simulation results.
